# Is there a way to ensure lazy evaluation of BOOST_TESTs message?

Tags: c++, boost-test

Is it possible to ensure that the message macro parameter of `BOOST_TEST` is only evaluated, if the check actually fails. Lazy evaluation seems to happen for human readable output format, but not for JUnit output format. ***Can I somehow make lazy evaluation work reliably for all output types?***

**MCVE**

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_module

#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <string>

struct S
{
    std::string m_value;
};

S* f(void)
{
    return nullptr;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(foo_test)
{
    S* result = f();
    BOOST_TEST(result == nullptr, "f() should return nullptr but returned a object with m_value = " << result->m_value);
}
```

This code works fine if I use human readable output format (`--log_format=HRF` command line option for executable). Using JUnit output (`--log_format=JUNIT` command line option) results in a access error, since the program attempts to get the size of a string at address `0`.

This is a bit unexpected, since I'd assume the `BOOST_TEST` macro would work similar to this

```
// not the real macro, but one that works in a way I'd expect it to work
#define BOOST_TEST(condition, message) if (!(condition)) { \
    some_output_stream << "The following test failed: " << #condition << std::endl \
                       << "Message: " << message; \
}
```

**Tested configurations:**

- boost 1.75.0
- Visual Studio 2017/2019 or g++ 8.x (Win 10 / Ubuntu 18)
- 64 bit